# How to Avoid name clashes with QMake if two files have the same name in a project

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have the following folder structure:

```
/linux
    -Process.h
Process.h
```

So in the folder Linux and before it there is a Process.cpp. Now when I try to compile this I run in trouble because it looks like QMake threats this like if the file Process.h shows up 2 times.

From the code Both classes in the files are separated by a namespace. One is simply

```
class Process.
```

The otherone with a namespace:

```
class Linux::Process
```

I had similar expediences with Visual Studio. There you could tell the build system to build with the paths your project is organized to not have this clash.

Any chance I can also solve that issue in qmake? Or do I really have to rename one file?

Comment: Why should these files have the same name?

Comment: To avoid long verbose names. By putting process.h in the linux folder it should be clear together with the namespace that its a linux process not the general process

Comment: You don't gain too much with it, I think. You might name files: `process.h` and `process_lnx.h`, especially if you must use namespaces anyways.